# Add info from a form to a table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

I have list of fields (on a sheet) in EXCEL document and a table. I need to add all info from input fields to this table after click the button. I need to write code of event on VBA. Can someone help with exemple how  to do this?

Here ia an example of my table:

[image]

Comment: Which version of Excel? (it makes a difference on how to add data to a table).  To clarify the inputs fields are on a User Form? or in objects on a sheet?  Perhaps add a screenshot of your form and table

Comment: I am using Office 2003. input fields are in objects on a sheet. I will add an example of a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo of a method for doing this

[image]

Table name `List1`
Text Boxes names `TextBox1` and `TextBox2`
Button name `CommandButton1`

Button click code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lst As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range
    Set lst = Me.ListObjects("List1")
    lst.Range.Activate
    Set rng = lst.InsertRowRange
    rng.Cells(1, lst.ListColumns("Item A").Index) = TextBox1.Value
    rng.Cells(1, lst.ListColumns("Item B").Index) = TextBox2.Value
End Sub
```

EDIT

If the List is on another sheet use this version

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lst As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lstRow As ListRow
    Set lst = Me.Parent.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("List1")
    Set lstRow = lst.ListRows.Add
    Set rng = lstRow.Range
    rng.Cells(1, lst.ListColumns("Item A").Index) = TextBox1.Value
    rng.Cells(1, lst.ListColumns("Item B").Index) = TextBox2.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot? I will try? Is it possible so give me a source code? I am new in EXCEL

Comment: here is my email: revolutionkpi@gmail.com

Comment: On which line?  You do need to adjust the object names to match your setup (ie `"List1"`, `"Item A"`,  `"Item B"`, `TextBox1`, `TextBox2`, and `CommandButton1` may be different in your app.)

Comment: One thought: you have actually created a `List` object, and not just formatted data to _look_ like a list?  (Lists are created from `Data/Lists` menu, or use `Ctrl-L`)

Comment: Sorry, but what can I do, if i have list on another sheet?

Comment: Set lst = Me.ListObjects("test!List1"), where test is a name of sheet, but it doesn't work

Comment: Answer Updated for List on another sheet